# Trigger.io: can I force a reload for all files and/or reset the reload history?

Tags: reload, trigger.io

Let me explain a little bit:

I'm currently using a CDN to push reloads, due to some issues I've had with Trigger's reload infrastructure. For some reason, the latest reloads I'm pushing don't seem to be getting through to the app.

I don't 100% understand how the reloads work (I suspect they go by some kind of queue in the order you push reloads), but my suspicion is that it's because one of the reloads in the queue got overwritten or deleted from my CDN, so the .apk (it's an Android app) is looking for an update that no longer exists on the server, and isn't skipping ahead to future updates.

Anyway, the question is: can I wipe the slate clean somehow, so that the apps stop looking for that reload?

Or, is there a way to force all apps to get the latest pushed reload? I know the reloads only work with changed files, but is there a way to say "this is the latest official version" and force apps to reload to that one?

UPDATE: I think it might have something to do with the active configuration I'm pushing to. Is there any way to determine which config ID (i.e. the one that most users are using) in the Reload panel matches up to which reload or manifest file I have on my CDN, so I know which version those users are on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a little background: when a device checks for a Reload update, it contacts the Trigger.io server to find out what the *most recent* applicable Reload update is, and where it is stored.

In your case, that will point the device towards a manifest file stored in your CDN, and the files referenced from it will be downloaded and swapped in.

So, the apps will automatically pick up the latest pushed Reload. If a Reload update is deleted or corrupted in the CDN, we still go back to the Trigger.io server so fixing the problem is just a case of re-pushing a newer Reload update.

There's no "out-of-the-box" way to connect which manifest files correspond to which config ID. One approach would be to install the app built from the relevant config ID, and let the Reload update occur. If you look at the debug log output as that Reload is happening, you can see what files are getting downloaded, and why.

Comment: Thanks, James. So just to confirm -- pushing a new Reload update will override whatever updates may be missing from the stream? And will the app still download all updated files?

Comment: I also think another confusing aspect (that may be at the root of my issue) was that as minor versions get released, my config changes and I end up pushing updates to the stream that don't reach my original user base. Do you recommend locking down a config to a minor version (e.g. 1.4.43) for a production build, or using 1.4. and just managing multiple release configs?

Comment: I'd recommend explicitly using minor platform versions; in fact, whenever you restore your configuration from the Reload tab in the Toolkit, we automatically put you on a minor platform version.

Comment: Thanks, James. I'll make sure to stick with minor versions from now on to avoid having to support a crazy number of fragmented users. As a usability suggestion for the future, the Reload tab might benefit from a more comprehensive history/log of what version was pushed to what reload stream, for reference.